# Solve k in this ODE: mv′(t)=mg−kv^2(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I have this question about finding the air resistance using the following differential equation:

```
*mv′(t)=mg−k(v^2)(t)*
```

where m is the mass of the downward-falling object, gravitational acceleration is g= 9.82, and k is a constant which describes the air resistance. 
According to the question, after many trials it was deduced that the constant fall speed is : 3.7√(m/A)m/s where m is mass in kg and A is the cross-section area in m^2.

So what is the value of k?

The only thing I know is that this equationis seprable but I am completely lost in this problem so any hint will be appreciated. Where should I start?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hint: "*constant* fall speed"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve initial value problem $m\dot{v} = mg - kv^2$ for $v(t)$ when $v(0) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272173/how-to-solve-initial-value-problem-m-dotv-mg-kv2-for-vt-when-v0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, don't try to solve a differential equation if you don't need to.

When the object is falling at its *constant* fall speed, its acceleration (by definition) is zero. You've been told $v$ and $g$. You now know $v'$. The only unknowns remaining in the question are $k$ and $m$. In principle, that's a problem if you're expecting a fixed number for $k$; the correct response to that issue is usually to just try to solve for $k$ in terms of $m$, and hope the $m$'s cancel out.

Comment: The m did cancel out and I got a value of k in terms of A. The next question is to solve the equation. I did solve it but I'm not sure of my answer as I got v'=-0.04. Is it possible to get the answer as a number, Isn't the answer of an ODE not a value but an equation?? Or did they mean to solve it without entering the value of k? Any Hints?? Thank alot!

Comment: The answer certainly shouldn't be a number; sometimes a value can be a correct answer to an ODE (if the solution is just a constant function) but not in this case. What concerns me particularly, though, is that your answer is about v' instead of v. Treat it the same way you would treat any separable differential equation; write v' as dv/dx, multiply both sides by dx, and then divide both sides by the part involving v. Note that that means dividing by (mg - kv^2).

Answer (score 0):

We first look at the stationeries states:
$v’(t)=0\Rightarrow k{v_0}^2=mg$. You can from here deduce $k$ since the constant fall speed $v_0$ is given.

Resolution: Now we put this expression into ODE. It comes:  $mdv=k({v_0}^2-v^2)dt\Rightarrow \frac{dv}{v^2-v_0^2}=-\frac{k}{m}dt$ then:
$$\int_{0}^{v}{\frac{dv}{v^2-v_0^2}}dv=\int_{0}^{\tau}{\frac{-k}{m}}dt$$ $\Rightarrow$
$$\frac{1}{v_0}arctanh {({\frac{v}{v_0}})}=\frac{k}{m}t$$ $\Rightarrow$ $$v=v_0\tanh(\frac{kv_0}{m}t)$$